# Converting all to uppercase

Tags: c++

Hey so I'm very new to c++ and trying to convert a word a user enters to all uppercase

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int size=10;
  int i =0;
  char arr[size];
  cout<<"Enter a word"<<endl;
  cin.get(arr,size);

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    if(islower(arr[i]))
    {
      cout<<toupper(arr[i])<<endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting numbers when I run this. What do I fix?

Comment: `toupper` returns `int`, so you have to cast it to `char`. Also, I suggest you use a `std::string` instead of an array.

Comment: `toupper` also takes an `int`, and this can lead to problems. See the Notes  section on [this `toupper` documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) for a quick discussion of the problem and a solution.

Comment: Note: There is no need to test for `islower`. `toupper`'s going to take care of it for you, so your code probably loses time.

Answer (score 5):

Don't write C-like C++, use the standard library to your advantage. Use an `std::string` and do something like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <string>  

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::toupper);
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or alternatively with a lambda:

```
std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); });
```

Comment: Can have a problem with converting signed `char` to `int`. [See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper).

Comment: `Don't write C-like C++`, yet you use the C version of `::toupper`. :P Consider changing it to `std::toupper`. :) `std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); });`

Comment: Good call. @Casey I honestly did not know about that distinction. I'll add that in as an alternative.

Comment: You forget to `#include <cctype>`. And `::toupper` is not conforming C++ because IIRC the implementation is allowed to use a `using` declaration to pull both overloads of `toupper` into the global scope (and it's bad style anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It is the time to learn one of bit-wise applications

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int mask = 0xDF;
    std::string str = "aBcdeqDsi";

    for(int i(0); i < str.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << static_cast<char>(str[i] & mask);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your assuming ASCII.  The bitwise operation may not work other code sets.